# AddFavorite JS doesn't work with chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm developing a website with bookmark function , I'm using this function `window.external.AddFavorite(location.href,document.title);`for chrome and IE it works fine in IE but for chrome it dose not ,,,, can anyone please direct me ... thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://help.dottoro.com/ljspwejw.php

> Opera, Google Chrome and Safari do not provide a way to add new elements to the Favorites (Bookmarks) from JavaScript.

There is currently no way to programmatically add a bookmark in Chrome, or any other modern browser, of course, except IE.

Comment: I don't think that is right. Maybe your answer is out of date. I have seen code examples of managing the favourites tree via JavaScript.

Comment: @gornvix No, this answer is up to date. The HTML5 API does not allow pages to manage or access your bookmarks. Depending on the environment (for example, in an extension context) that you are running your code in, however, different APIs might be available which may allow this type of operations. That is out of the scope of this question though.